# Running a SQL Server stored proecdure with OPENROWSET in VB.Net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am trying to automatically import tables from an excel sheet into a table in an SQL database via VB.net. So far I have done the following:

I created a stored procedure in the database which imports the table via openrowset:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ImportTable   
AS   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1   
    EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1

    SELECT * 
    INTO [Table]
    FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                    'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\ExcelFile.xlsm', Table$);
GO
```

Once created this procedure works perfectly when executed in SSMS.

I then wrote a script in VB.net to run the stored procedure with the same login details:

```
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim sqlCon As SqlConnection

    ' Open a database connection and use it to run the stored procedure

    ConnectionString = "Data Source=ServerName;" &
                       "Initial Catalog=DBName;" &
                       "User=UserName;" &
                       "Password=Password;" &
                       "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    sqlCon = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

    Using (sqlCon)

        Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand

        sqlComm.Connection = sqlCon

        sqlComm.CommandText = "ImportTable"
        sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        sqlCon.Open()

        sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Using
```

However when I try to run the SP in VB.net (or VB excel) I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
>   OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".'

I have looked around and found multiple threads on getting this to work in SSMS, but no solutions for a situation where it runs fine in SSMS but not in VB.net.

Any idea why the SP wont run through a method external to SSMS?

Craig

Comment: My first guess is that it won't work with windows authentication outside SSMS. You may need to setup admin user with name and password on DB, something like 'sa' and use those credentials instead. It may not need to be admin, I am no sure but I think it needs to be user setup on Sql Server DB.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to run the SP in VB.Net with both windows authentication and an admin account I created for the DB. Both work in SSMS but neither outside of it :s

Comment: Are you really passing user id / password AND specifying integrated security? Try not doing that.

Comment: I just removed that line and still get the same error I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure the Excel file isn't open.

Then you need to check whether you have installed the 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components which is necessary for Microsoft OLEDB ACE 12.0 driver to work.

or you can

```
USE [master] 

GO 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 

GO 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 

GO
```

Nice [Link](https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2012/07/10/querying-excel-2010-from-sql-server-in-64-bit-environment/)

Comment: Hi Sandeep, thanks for the quick response. I have tried your suggestions and also worked through every point in the link you provided, still no joy I'm afraid.